# How to create a folder with subfolder for each project created?

Tags: python, django

How can I create a folder and subfolders each time, I am creating a project. The location of the folders could be located in

```
media ----- Projects |----Project 1 |-----Subfolder 1
                     |              |-----Subfolder 2
                     |              |-----Subfolder 3
                     |
                     |----Project 2 |-----Subfolder 1
                     |              |-----Subfolder 2
                     |              |-----Subfolder 3
                     |
                     |----Project 3 |-----Subfolder 1
                                    |-----Subfolder 2
                                    |-----Subfolder 3
```

**views.py**

```
def create_project(request):
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save(commit=False)
            project.save()
            return render(request, 'projects/detail.html', {'project': project})
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'projects/create_project.html', context)
```

Comment: are you asking how to manipulate the file system from django view?

Comment: I can upload a file or image from the django view. What I would like to do is each time I am creating a project, it also create some one folder and a few subfolders. This would help me to keep a record of the documents and infos saved in the model.

Comment: do you mean new django project or something internal for the app you are developing

Comment: It is something for the app that I am developing. Lets say, I will be using dropbox later on. Instead project, we call it Playlist. Each playlist is containing songs ordered by artists.   And Each time, I am creating a new playlist, a new folder will be created on the dropbox. Each folder, will also contains subfolders named by their artists and contains the songs. This way, I could still access the files on the dropbox if I`ve got any issues with the website.

Comment: ok, see me comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the file system from django views by using the built-in python functions. To do that you need to import the os module. A sample code is shows an excerpt from [the article](https://www.zentut.com/python-tutorial/working-with-directory/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20directory,under%20c%3A%5Ctemp%20directory.):

```
import os;
#will check if c:\temp\python exists and if no will create it
dir = os.path.join("C:\\","temp","python")
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir)
```

when using it from django you need to be aware that the process that runs your app has limited permissions, so some locations will not be accessible. When executing from django view the relative path is set to **PROJECT_ROOT**(which you define in your settings.py). The code above however does not relate to dropbox. In order to manage the folders in dropbox you need to use the API they provide for that.

As an additional note, when uploading files django will automatically create folder(if you specified one in the ['upload_to' parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield) of the FileField) in your media folder. You can alter that behavior by replacing upload_to with a function that can return different path depending on what you are saving. If you want to go in that direction [this may be usefull](http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2010/08/try-me-out.html)